# How to create a lib to manipulate and show a new image format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, image-processing, format

I work with some .WSQ images (Wavelet Scalar Quantization) and I can't display neither manipulate them in javaScript. (I can't change the image format for another one like .jpg or .png, it needs to be the original .wsq)

I think a good way to deal with it is developing a library that allows to display and manipulate these images in the browser, but I don't know where to start it.

Anybody knows how can I do it? Any material I can read to help me understand how it is done? (For example, imagine I'm creating a way to display jpeg images in browser with javascript for the first time, what should I do?)

Comment: I think it's going to be hard trying to get images in this format to show up "as is" in a web browser. I found this php package you could use (if you have access to a php app server) to translate images back and forth: https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/wsq-image-library-for-php.540298/

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I really need to use directly this format using javascript on common browser like chrome, safari and firefox and I would like to understand where should I start looking for it.

Comment: It's not going to work. And questions of this type "...where should I start looking..." are off-topic on SO

Comment: I believe the Javascript version of the C++ OpenCV project, i.e. OpenCVjs, uses Emscripten to compile the C++ to WebAsm which you can use in a browser so maybe you can find some C++ code and run that through Emscripten in a similar way... just guessing.